# Show axis at center, but keep labels on the left

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot a distribution which is centred around zero, and as such I want to show the y-axis spine at 0, but I want to keep the tick labels themselves to the left of the graph (i.e. outside the plot area). I thought this might be achievable through `tick_params`, but the `labelleft` option seems to keep the labels in the centre. A short example is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

vals = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=300)
bins = range(int(min(vals)), int(max(vals))+1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
ax.hist(vals, bins=bins)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

ax.grid(axis='y', which='major', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

This gives you:

[image: Histogram centred at zero]

I would like the labels to be at the left end of the gridlines, rather than the centre of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but you can set left spines invisible and draw a straight line at 0:

```
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

ax.plot((0,0), (0,ax.get_ylim()[-1]),color='k',linewidth=1)
ax.grid(axis='y', which='major', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Not a bad first idea, though I think I'd do the vertical line with `ax.axvline(x=0, color='k', lw=1)` as it should be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

On possibility is to instruct the tick labels to use the "Axes coordinates" for their x position, and the "Data coordinates" for their y position. This implies changing their `tranform` property.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

np.random.seed(1)

vals = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=300)
bins = range(int(min(vals)), int(max(vals))+1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(vals, bins=bins)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

ax.grid(axis='y', which='major', alpha=0.5)

trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes,ax.transData)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), 'transform', trans)

plt.show()
```

[image]