# Move x-axis to data=0 but keep tick labels at the bottom

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, xticks

I would like to move the line of the x-axis (with all the corresponding ticks) x=0. But the tick-labels should be positioned at the bottom of the figure, to prevent clutter in the graph.

[Show axis at center, but keep labels on the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669981/show-axis-at-center-but-keep-labels-on-the-left/56670291#comment136388675_56670291)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np

# Generate some sample data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Plot the data
ax.plot(x, y)
# Move the x-axis to the bottom
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes,ax.transData)
# plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), 'transform', trans)  # this returns a plot with zero height
plt.show()
```

I would like to move the axis itself including the ticks. This makes working with a grid and logarithmic scale for the ticks easier. Therefore a solution with a horizontal line lke `ax.axhline(y=0)` is not a good solution and is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you're looking to apply the transformer on the `xaxis`, like this:

```
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData,ax.transAxes)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), 'transform', trans)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]